# How do I get the match in a Regex.Replace into the replacement string?

Tags: c#, regex

I need the match in the Regex.Replace to be part of the replacement string. For example, if I want to change DOMAIN to `<a>DOMAIN</a>`, wherever it says DOMAIN. How do I get DOMAIN into the match?

`regex.Replace(input, String.Format("<a>{0}</a>" WHAT_HERE?));`

How do I find the "WHAT_HERE?"?

Comment: Is that string literal "Domain" or can be anything? Post some sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [grouping construct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx) `(...)`:

```
string replaced = Regex.Replace("<input>", "(DOMAIN)", "<a>$1</a>");
```

**Example:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/Hu0cEO

Answer (score 0):

Andrew's answer is correct, here's how you'd do it if you wanted to name the grouping and then replace it by name (expanded from Andrew's dotnetfiddle):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string result = Regex.Replace("This is a test to see if DOMAIN gets replaced properly. DOMAIN", "(?<myName>DOMAIN)", "<a>${myName}</a>");

        result.Dump();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
This is a test to see if <a>DOMAIN</a> gets replaced properly. <a>DOMAIN</a>
```